# Обработка ошибок в Android Java

Tags: java, android

Проблема такая: пишу приложения с соединением с сервером. Делаю простой `AsyncTask` с Callback. Все хорошо но при проблеме с соединением у меня не обрабатывается как положено а просто выкидывает. Вот код запроса:

```
package com.example.drawer.drawer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by user on 29.11.2017.
 */
public class AsyncQuery extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private Context context;
    private String postParams;
    private Callback callBack;
    private String constUrl;

    AsyncQuery(Context c, String url, String p, Callback back){
        context = c;
        postParams = p;
        callBack = back;
        constUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            String myURL = constUrl;
            String param = postParams;
            byte[] data = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(myURL);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(param.getBytes().length));
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                data = param.getBytes("UTF-8");
                os.write(data);
                data = null;

                conn.connect();
                int responseCode= conn.getResponseCode();

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    is = conn.getInputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // Такого вот размера буфер
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    data = baos.toByteArray();
                    String rs = new String(data, "UTF-8");

                    return rs;
                }else{
                    callBack.onReqFail(false);
                    return null;
                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                callBack.onFail("MalformedURLException:");
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                callBack.onFail("IOException:");
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                callBack.onFail("Exception:");
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            callBack.onFail("Exception:");
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( String rs) {
        super.onPostExecute(rs);
        if (rs != null){
            callBack.onSuccess(rs);
        }

    }

}
```

А вот код Сallback обработки:

```
@Override
public void onReqFail(Boolean str){
    if (str == false){
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusForQuery);
        txt.setText("Ошибка сети проверте подключения к интернету");
    }
}

@Override
public void onFail(String rs) {

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusForQuery);
    txt.setText(rs);
}
```

Что скажете?

Comment: Нужен стектрейс.

Comment: Что такое стектрейс?

Comment: @user8978194 это логи!

Comment: тебя учили дебажить, чек боксы ставить??? в каком месте проблема начинается? что возвращает колбэк?

Comment: попробуй еще сделать логирование. Легче ошибки ловить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя изменять UI из фонового потока - у Вас это все вызовы `callBack` в `doInBackground`
Работу с UI нужно переводить в главный поток с помощью Handler или `Activity.runOnUiThread()` или `View.post()`.
Или вызывать `callback` в `onPostExecute`. Для этого нужно либо возвращать в `doInBackground` специальное значение при ошибке и проверять его в `onPostExecute`, либо записывать ошибку в поле и проверять это поле.

Comment: Точно! Ну я и тупанул

Comment: а как подскажешь сделать?

Comment: Помогло большое Спасибо